# Displaying results from 00:00 Until 23:59

Tags: c#

I have to display a table with today soccer matches with time interval from 00:00 until 23:59
This is the query that i used

```
 l2 = matches.FindAll(i => i.MatchDate >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-DateTime.Now.Hour).AddMinutes(-DateTime.Now.Minute).AddSeconds(-DateTime.Now.Second) && i.MatchDate <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(DateTime.Now.Hour).AddMinutes(DateTime.Now.Minute).AddSeconds(DateTime.Now.Second)).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the question? Is this working as expected?
Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for tips on asking questions on SO.

Comment: No,it is not working as expected

Comment: so break it down and debug whats wrong with it

Comment: It seems like you are overcomplicating this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

best to truncate to dates (ie no time):

```
matches.FindAll(i => i.MatchDate.Date == DateTime.Today)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to check time :

```
l2 = matches.Where(i => i.MatchDate >=DateTime.Today && i.MatchDate <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)).ToList();
```

if not - mikelegg's answer is correct one.